# How do you solve $2^x-x=3$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponential-function, roots, lambert-w

Maybe it's a simple question, but I can't figure it out. How do you solve $2^x-x=3$? Using logarithms? I could write $\log_2(x-3)=x$, but then what?

Thank you!

Comment: I would not expect this to have a pleasant analytic solution, though of course you can solve it numerically.  I get $x\in \{-2.8625,\,2.44491\}$.  There should (I think)  be a solution in terms of the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) though that doesn't really help much.

Comment: This, like many other simple to state equations who combine multiple different types of functions (*e.g. exponentials and polynomials*), will likely have no "elementary" solution in general and you would need to satisfy yourself with either finding the solution by inspection (*if it is an easy to state solution*) or to approximate the solution via numerical methods.

Comment: See the following related definitions: [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function), [Lambert W Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function), [Newton's Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).

Comment: I think the question should be: $2^x + x = 3$

Comment: @The2nd and why do you think that?  Because $2^1+1=3$?  Just because that question has a solution you can find by inspection does not mean that the related questions who have no immediately identifiable solution by inspection are any less relevant of questions to be asking.  It is perfectly reasonable to ask the question for $2^x-x=3$ instead of $2^x+x=3$, *especially* since the answer for $2^x-x=3$ is much less obvious and would warrant *asking*.

Comment: @The2nd It might depend on who's asking and who's being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a step-by-step Lambert W solution (see Robert's answer).
Recall the definition: $ae^a = b\Longleftrightarrow a = W(b)$.
So we try to get our equation into the form $ae^a = b$.
$$
2^x-x=3
\\
2^x=x+3
\\
2^{x+3}=8(x+3)
\\
e^{(x+3)\log 2}=8(x+3)
\\
\frac{-\log 2}{8}=-(x+3)\log 2\; e^{-(x+3)\log 2}
\\
W\left(\frac{-\log 2}{8}\right)=-(x+3)\log 2
\\
\frac{1}{\log 2}W\left(\frac{-\log 2}{8}\right)=-(x+3)
\\
x = -3-\frac{1}{\log 2}W\left(\frac{-\log 2}{8}\right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

The solutions are
$$ x = -3 -{\frac {{\rm W} \left(-\ln  \left( 2 \right)/8 \right) }{\ln  \left( 2 \right) }}
$$
where $W$ is a branch of the Lambert W function. There are two real solutions,
approximately $-2.862500372$ and $2.444907554$, corresponding to the principal and the "$-1$" branch respectively.

Comment: Can the Lambert W function be used to find the exact answer, or only an approximation?

Comment: Only approximations. The same way the function $\sin(x)$ and $e^x$ give only approximations. Calculating the value of a polynomial gives an "exact" value, but most functions including the square root function give only approximations for the vast majority of values. "Exact" values are a minority in maths.

Comment: $W(x)$ is an "exact" value of $w$ such that $w e^w = x$. In general it can't be expressed in terms of more elementary functions.  If you want a numerical answer, you can get an approximation.